# How can i write Linq of this query ? ( Linq C#)

Tags: sql, linq

Sql Query is :

```
select T1.SellerId , count(T2.productId)
 from
tbl_1 T1 
left join
tbl_2 T2
on T1.SellerId = T2.sellerId
where VisitorUserId = 'bf8581b04429fdf56c6ebc' 
group by T1.SellerId
```

---

I Need This SQL Query in Linq C#.

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not somewhere to post a list of needs.  Try something and if it fails, ask a question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `VisitorUserId` is a column of `tbl_1` and assuming you use ORM like Entity Framework with navigation properties for foreign keys relationships it should be smth like this:

```
context.tbl_1
    .Where(i => i.VisitorUserId = 'bf8581b04429fdf56c6ebc')
    .Select(i => new { SellerId = i.SellerId, ProductCount = i.tbl_2.Count() })
```